# What is syntax to specify SQL Server column default value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2012.

Using VS 2012 IDE table designer, I have added a default value and the system generated this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tVEHICLES]
    ADD [DT_ACTIVE_EVENT] DATE DEFAULT (('1980-01-01')) NULL;
```

Q1:  My main question is why are there double parentheses "*(( value ))*"?

Q2:  Does the syntax require double-parentheses?

Q3:  What about ...*DEFAULT '1980-01-01' NULL;*  ?

Thanks in advance... John

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Also, asking "what about" is really unclear. But if you mean NULL, it's like always, it allows nulls.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies.  So, I get two demerits for asking a question that I could not find ANY documented syntax and asked here as to what the parentheses are put on a generated statement by VS-2012.  Replies state that the parens are not required, but no one said "why" double-parens are used and what purpose are the double-parens.  I do not want to start a comment-debate. I was just looking for the answers to my Q's.  Regarding What about...It shows the default without any parens -- no question about the NULL.  Sorry for me being so stupid, ok mates?

Answer (score 1):

Is it really easier to ask the question than to try the code?

The parentheses are not needed.  [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0264f/1) is a SQL Fiddle.

Note how this behaves:

- If you do not include the column in the `insert` (or insert the default explicitly), you will get the default.
- You can still insert `NULL` into the column.

Often, columns with default values have `NOT NULL` constraints.

Comment: Thank you for you reply and your valuable behavior reply.  In this case, the 01-01-1980 represents the earliest date allowed as a history-date.  Please read my comment above.  Thanks for the fiddle-link, but I do not know how to start fiddle on my own.